# iPhone calendar reminder +

Tags: iphone

My iPhone's calendar + icon has suddenly gone gray and will not allow me to add a reminder. I read through the answers here and it was suggested to slide on calendar in all accounts. That was already done and still nothing. Any suggestions?  Im missin my reminders!!!

Answer (score 1):

Reminders are added in the Reminders app, not the Calendar app. Use the Reminders app to create reminders.